# GetGenericArguments in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I have issue related to GetGenericArguments in Unity.

In Unity

```
Dictionary<byte, object>[] array = new Dictionary<byte, object>[]
{
   new Dictionary<byte, object>() { { 0, "0" }, {1, "1"} },
   new Dictionary<byte, object>() { { 0, "00" }, {1, "11"} }
};

var types = array.GetType().GetGenericArguments();
```

`types` has 0 elements, but in online compiler (fiddle for example), or console app 2 elements: Byte, Object.

This affects on Photon Library on client side. Why the method behaves differently?

Answer (score 0):

From the [IsGenericType documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isgenerictype?view=net-6.0):

> Note
>
> The IsGenericType property returns false if the immediate type is not generic. For example, an array whose elements are of type A<int> [...] is not itself a generic type.

So where you have `Dictionary<byte, object>[] array`, the *immediate* type is an array, not a Dictionary, so it's "not generic" which is why GetGenericArguments is returning nothing - it's no generic so there are no generic arguments to get.

Since you know it's an array maybe you could try indexing into the first element, like

```
if(array.length > 0)
{
    var types = array[0].GetType().GetGenericArguments();
}
```